# How to return function as a value in jQuery Ajax request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json.net

I am currently working on `ASP.NET Web Forms`. I use `DataTables` to show my data on the front end. I moved the initialization to the back end so now in order to load the `DataTable` I make `Ajax` request using `jQuery` which returns all expected configurations. The problem is that when I want to render something image/span tag/something else more specific in any of the columns I need to provide a function as an argument.

In the original variant, where the configuration is in the view I simply have:

```
 "mRender": function () {
      return '<span class="btnDelete">...</span>'
      }
```

and I'm fine. Now I need to execute the same function but sending it from the server side along with the other data. So my problem is, how to actually write my code so that the function get's executed on the front end.

I'm using `JSON.NET` to handle the `Ajax` requests and my code right now is :

```
        Column = new JObject();
        Column.sTitle = "Actions";
        Column.mData = null;
        Column.bSortable = false;
        Column.mRender = "function () { return '<span class=btnEdit>Btn</span>' }";
        Columns.aoColumns.Add(Column);
```

but the front end reads this as an ordinary string and nothing is executed. Is there a way to accomplish such a task?

Comment: Have you tried using [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)?

Comment: @Brian Rogers What I would like is to make it work without writing additional `JS` logic. Right now it's working with `eval()` but I have to iterate the result find the `mRender` keys and `eval()` the values and if some day I have to add function somewhere else I'll have to add code that will check for that too and so on. So I was wondering if there is solution entirely on the server side. Maybe I can include `eval()` on the server side in such a way that it's executed?